# file location to System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, image-processing, stream

I have this method

```
public void SetSource(Stream streamSource);
```

which sets the source of `BitmapSource`, is there a way to convert my URI or my image file location and pass it as a stream?

(another issue):

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("../images/MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative);
        BitmapImage btmp1 = new BitmapImage(uri);
        WriteableBitmap btmp = new WriteableBitmap(btmp1);
```

I am getting an error NULL exception when creating an instance of btmp (because it is expecting a BitmapImageSource)...but how do I get what I am after?

thanks,

Voodoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `FileStream`:

```
thingy.SetSource(new FileStream(path));
```

Comment: do I have to give Absolute path? what if I want to tell it that it's in the images folder from the root ?

Comment: I tried [new BitmapSource().SetSource(new FileStream(@"C:\images\myimage.png", FileMode.Open));" ...but it is complaining that Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource'

Comment: Change it to `new BitmapImage()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute))
```

If you have a relative path, pass `UriKind.Relative`.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that as well. But I am always getting NULL exception when using the BitMapImage object....could it be because my xap is in another directory? how do I make sure that my URI is not failing?